# Error on change form action

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm changing the form action with:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('pdf').onclick = addExportEvent;
    document.getElementById('xls').onclick = addExportEvent;
    document.getElementById('xml').onclick = addExportEvent;
    document.getElementById('csv').onclick = addExportEvent;
}

function addExportEvent() {
    data = grid.getAllGridData();
    document.getElementById('dados').setAttribute('value', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)));

    formulario = document.getElementById('formulario'); // Line 55!
    formulario.action = 'php/' + this.id + '.php';
    formulario.submit();

    return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work with Internet Explorer. It returns the following error:

```
Message: The object doesn't support the property or method.
Line: 55
Character: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.site.com/javascript/scripts.js
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the `var` keyword when declaring variables in Javascript.  e.g. `var data = grid.getAllGridData()`.  This will save you scoping related headaches later on.

Comment: On a side note, Internet Explorer 7 and earlier are very inaccurate with scripting error line numbers.  This is improved in IE 8 but for all I know there may still be some situations where the line number is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think  Andy E's head's comment hit it on the, well, head. You are assigning the correct element, but not declaring it using var which makes IE gag and choke and all kinds of bad stuff. Other browsers handle this just fine. So you are trying to access formulario instead of declaring it, which means it never gets the value of id: `formulario`

```
function addExportEvent() {
    var data = grid.getAllGridData();
    document.getElementById('dados').setAttribute('value', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)));

    var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario'); // Line 55!
    formulario.action = 'php/' + this.id + '.php';
    formulario.submit();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: But formulario is an HTML element and it works in browsers like Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera...
Before I was doing:

formulario.setAttribute('action', 'php/' + this.id + '.php');

Comment: Yeap, Andy was right! I put var keyword and everything is working!
Thanks guys!